# T-SQL selecting all col to update in merge

Tags: sql

Maybe that stupid question, but I don't know how to describe my problem to uncle google.

I have two simple tables with 3 rows: ID, Name, SomeVal;

Now I want update them with merge, and that's simple:

```
MERGE Locations T
USING Locations_2 S ON T.ID=S.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
  SET 
    T.Name=S.Name, 
    T.SomeVal=S.SomeVal;
```

Ok, that works, but I wrote every column name by hand. So, when I want to update for example table with 30 columns, writing everything by hand will be painful. So, is there any option to update every column in the table no matter how many columns it has?
I tried "*". It is `UPDATE SET T.*=S.*`, and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I normally do when I want to be time efficient (or lazy, depending on your view) is this:

Run this command:

```
sp_help TableName;
```

Copy/paste the first column, then hold down Alt whilst dragging the mouse cursor in front of the column names. This way I can then type one comma in front of all the fields. Then I do the same after the field name except with an = sign.

That's the only shortcut I can think to help you, and has saved me hours of typing over the years.

Comment: Thanks. That is very helpful :D

Answer (score 1):

No. Merge statements are very verbose. You can hack a shortcut by scripting your table as CREATE, copy the column names using SHIFT + ALT to select a large swath of them, then paste them into the MERGE query, hit space, add the = sign, then paste again.

The statement is one direction, (i.e., you can't update S with T; only T can be updated) so you don't *strictly* need to provide the source/destination alias for each column.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can highlight your table, hit ALT+F1 to return the column listing.